# Working Voltage for Basic/Reinforced Isolation (ACS712)

Tags: isolation, current-sensing

I'm planing to use current sense chip [ACS712](https://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/files/datasheets/acs712-datasheet.ashx).
I don't understand some values in its datasheet, page 2 (Isolation Characteristics).

I understand "Dielectric Strength Test Voltage - 2100VAC" - that is isolation between pins 1-4 and 5-8. Pretty clear.
But what mean these values?

- Working Voltage for Basic Isolation - 354 VDC
- Working Voltage for Reinforced Isolation - 184 VDC

I'm planning to use it to measure current in mains (230Vac) and I'm really confused with those parameters.

Comment: I'm planning to use this chip, whose datasheet's first page says "not recommended for new designs". While this is fine for "private" and one-off designs, why take the risk of using a chip that the manufacturer deems inappropriate?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm just a hobbyist, not a professional. This is going to be one-off. Actually I'm interested in building an electronic circuit breaker (inspired by xraytonyb on youtube)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to read *UL standard 60950-1, 1st Edition* as cited in that exact table! Google can give you that document, you're looking for clause 1.2.9.2 to 1.2.9.5.

Basically, to cite the above document scientifically:

> 1.2.9.2 BASIC INSULATION :
>  insulation to provide basic protection against electric shock
>
> 1.2.9.3 SUPPLEMENTARY INSULATION :
>  independent insulation applied in addition to BASIC INSULATION in order to reduce the risk of
>   electric shock in the event of a failure of the BASIC INSULATION
>
> 1.2.9.4 DOUBLE INSULATION :
>  insulation comprising both BASIC INSULATION and SUPPLEMENTARY INSULATION
>
> 1.2.9.5 REINFORCED INSULATION :
>  single insulation system that provides a degree of protection against electric shock equivalent to
>   DOUBLE INSULATION under the conditions specified in this standard

Meaning that for the lower voltage range, this chip might be used and the isolation can be labeled as "reinforced", whereas it's only basic if used in the higher voltage range.

In other words, the thing is designed so that you can think it being "as secure as say a cable with isolation, plus another isolating measure in case that isolation fails". This makes a difference in applications where you need the double isolation-equivalence. I can't tell you whether that is required for your application – chances are you want to put all this in a foolproof and safe enclosure, so that it's not overly critical if everything inside fails and the measurement side of the chip accidentally sees 230V.

Also, 230V might indicate that UL standards don't matter to you, at all.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. The citation actually did not help me to understand it, but your commentary did ;) Thank you again.

Comment: Just a side question, what do you mean by "230V might indicate that UL standards don't matter to you, at all"? You mean by that UL is for US market and 230V is actually in another markets? Yes, you are right in that case. But it matters to me indirectly. I prefer to be on the safe side (probably more than necessary)